# Can turbulence be predicted from entropy?

Tags: fluid-dynamics, flow, aerodynamics, turbulence, navier-stokes

Frozen water has lower entropy than liquid water.
This is true for most solid/liquid transitions.

Clearly a solid can't flow with turbulence ( although glass does flow over many years as can be seen where some windows are thicker at the base).
Liquids do flow with turbulence over time scales of seconds or minutes.
Can the entropy of a liquid or gas be used to predict its Reynolds Number?

The Reynolds number is the ratio of inertial forces to viscous forces (viscous forces tend to inhibit turbulence).When the inertial forces are too great turbulence appears because the stickiness of the molecules isn't enough to keep molecules clinging together and order in the liquid breaks down.